# Swift: The given data was not valid JSON

Tags: json, swift

Since yesterday when I updated xCode I'm receiving error in the console and I'm not getting my data from the API. I'm getting this error:

`dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))`

What I don't understand is that I never had any issues before and now I get this error out of nowhere, and I also don't know if the problem is server sided or in my swift code...
Here if how I make the request:

```
        //    -- 1 -- Create an URL
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            //    -- 2 -- Create a URLSession
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    self.parseJSON(EventDatas: safeData)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func parseJSON(EventDatas: Data){
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(LuxCategoryData.self, from: EventDatas)
            var test: [Int] = []
            for object in decodedData.category {
                let category: CategoryData = CategoryData()
                category.idCategory = object.idCategory
                category.dtTitle = object.dtTitle
                dropDown.optionArray.append(category.dtTitle)
                test.append(Int(category.idCategory)!)
                self.categoryData.append(category)
            }
            dropDown.optionIds = test
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Here is the decodable struct I use to parse the JSON:

```
struct LuxCategoryData : Decodable {
    let category: [Category]
}

struct Category: Decodable {
    let idCategory: String;
    let dtTitle: String;
}
```

This is how my JSON look like when I make a request in the browser:

```
{
 category: [
  {
   idCategory: "1",
   dtTitle: "Cinema"
  },
  {
   idCategory: "2",
   dtTitle: "Bar"
  },
  {
   idCategory: "5",
   dtTitle: "Danse" 
  },
  { 
   idCategory: "6",
   dtTitle: "Nightlife"
  },
  {
   idCategory: "10",
   dtTitle: "Music"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: In almost all cases the message *Invalid value around character 0* means that the received data is HTML rather than JSON. Create a string from the data and `print` it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *JSON* you provided doesn't contain `" "` around the keys. That's why it is giving *invalid JSON error*.

Try with the below *JSON* format,

```
{"category":[{"idCategory":"1","dtTitle":"Cinema"},{"idCategory":"2","dtTitle":"Bar"},{"idCategory":"5","dtTitle":"Danse"},{"idCategory":"6","dtTitle":"Nightlife"},{"idCategory":"10","dtTitle":"Music"}]}
```

Comment: In terms of JSON character 0 **is** valid. I guess the error message about missing double quotes is different.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work... one of my colleagues tried my app on his xCode and all worked fine.... I now tried to down grade xCode with a older version and I get the same error. It's weird...

Answer (score 2):

`Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   category: [{            idCa
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'`

https://jsonlint.com/